# In Shopify, using REST API's or GraphQL, can I simultaneously open and work with two stores

Tags: rest, graphql, shopify

I need to duplicate some information between two stores ( one being the source store and the other the destination store ) .. can I open access to both stores, do a fetch data query on the source store and then mutate to the destination store, rather than having to use an intermediate storage file or memory, as the data size is large.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. In the most simple case you need a private app for each of the two stores. Then your calls to the REST or GraphQL API are constructed in such a way that they address the respectiv store. In Python this might look like the follwing

```
import base64
import requests

API_VERSION = '2022-01'
API_KEY1 = "API_KEY for private app of store 1")
PASSWORD1 = "PASSWORD for private app of store 1")
CREDENTIAL1 = f'{API_KEY1}:{PASSWORD1}'
auth = base64.b64encode(CREDENTIAL1.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
headers1 = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", 'Authorization': 'Basic '+auth}

SHOP1 = 'name of store1 i.g. example1.myshopify.com'
base1 = f'https://{SHOP1}/admin/api/{API_VERSION}/'

API_KEY2 = "API_KEY for private app of store 2")
PASSWORD2 = "PASSWORD for private app of store 2")
CREDENTIAL2 = f'{API_KEY2}:{PASSWORD2}'
auth = base64.b64encode(CREDENTIAL2.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
headers2 = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", 'Authorization': 'Basic '+auth}   

SHOP2 = 'name of store2 i.g. example2.myshopify.com'
base2 = f'https://{SHOP2}/admin/api/{API_VERSION}/'

# example call to the first store
r1 = requests.get(base1+'products/count.json',headers=headers1)

# example call to the second store
r2 = requests.get(base2+'products/count.json',headers=headers2)
```